# Compare string][] array with set of objects. And return set with duplicated ones

Tags: java, java-8

I would like to compare the array of strings with the set of object, where object has string field. And then return object which equals to the given string. But I would like to avoid for each loops if possible.

Any idea how could I do it with stream api?

So let me paste some example code:

```
    class TestObj {

    private String str;
    private String name;

    public TestObj(String str, String name) {
        this.setStr(str);
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

}
```

And the actual code is:

```
    Set<TestObj> allObjects = new HashSet<>();
    allObjects.add(new TestObj("s", "aaa"));
    allObjects.add(new TestObj("d", "uuu"));
    allObjects.add(new TestObj("a", "ggg"));
    allObjects.add(new TestObj("c", "dd"));

    String[] arr = {"a", "b", "e", "f"};

    Set<TestObj> objectsToReturn = new HashSet<>();


    for (String string : arr) {
        for (TestObj testObj : objectsToReturn) {
            if(string.equals(testObj.getStr())) {
                objectsToReturn.add(testObj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid for each loops?

Comment: You can of course hardcode 16 if statements if you would like to not have a loop

Comment: *Any idea how could I do it with stream api?* -> you know that streams are not *magic* but they use ("very bad") for-loops too internally

Comment: Change your for each loops to standard for loops. Sorted.

Comment: @Lino First, For learning purposes. Second, I know what they are using below. But it is still more readable than loops. At least for me. And for that reason I would like to avoid loops if possible. Thats all. But seems like some people want to add some more depth to the question.

Comment: @Suule if it's for learning purposes, then why don't you try to come up with a solution yourself? And then show us where you're stuck or what you don't understand. That's the process of learning, not: *I have **this**, gimme **that** plz*

Comment: @Lino Could you unload your nervers somewhere else? It seems like you just want to start quarrels. Thanks for your help and bye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to first stress that there is *nothing wrong* with doing this with for each loops. Using streams might even introduce some overhead.

That said, one way to do it with streams is:

```
String[] arr = {"a", "b", "e", "f"};
List<String> arrList = Arrays.asList(arr); // create a List from the array so that we can call "contains".
                                           // If the array is constant, you should just directly create a List instead.

Set<TestObj> objectsToReturn =
        allObjects.stream()
        .filter(x -> arrList.contains(x.getStr()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If your array is sorted, you don't need the `List` and you can call `binarySearch` to see if the array contains the element:

```
Set<TestObj> objectsToReturn =
        allObjects.stream()
        .filter(x -> Arrays.binarySearch(arr, x.getStr()) >= 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: If the `arr` is sorted, you could use `.filter(x -> Arrays.binarySearch(arr, x.getStr()) >= 0)`

Comment: @Lino Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise, if the array could be rather large, it’s better to use `.filter(new HashSet<>( Arrays.asList(arr))::contains)`.

Answer (score -2):

You are comparing the Strings to the wrong objects. In the inner for-each loop you are iterating through objectsToReturn, which is empty. To fix it just change:

```
for (TestObj testObj : objectsToReturn) {
```

to:

```
for (TestObj testObj : allObjects) {
```